# external resolve dns linux bind9

Tags: linux, dns, debian, bind9

I'm 3 days trying to fix my nameservers to a .tk domain, just for testing because I'm going to not go to .com. I wanted to understand how I could solve my DNS even outside and not just on a private network. Repeat the server configuration:

**named.conf.options**

```
    options {
        directory "/var/cache/bind";

        // If there is a firewall between you and nameservers you want
        // to talk to, you may need to fix the firewall to allow multiple
        // ports to talk.  See http://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/800113

        // If your ISP provided one or more IP addresses for stable 
        // nameservers, you probably want to use them as forwarders.  
        // Uncomment the following block, and insert the addresses replacing 
        // the all-0's placeholder.

        // forwarders {
        //      0.0.0.0;
        // };

        //========================================================================
        // If BIND logs error messages about the root key being expired,
        // you will need to update your keys.  See https://www.isc.org/bind-keys
        //========================================================================
        dnssec-validation auto;

        auth-nxdomain no;    # conform to RFC1035
        listen-on-v6 { any; };
};
```

**named.conf.local**

```
    //
// Do any local configuration here
//

// Consider adding the 1918 zones here, if they are not used in your
// organization
//include "/etc/bind/zones.rfc1918";

zone "fresky.tk" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.fresky.tk";
};

zone "33.163.31.176.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "/etc/bind/zones/db.33.163.31.176.in-addr.arpa";
};
```

**ZONE *fresky.tk***

```
;
; BIND data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     ns1.fresky.tk. admin.fresky.tk. (
                     2006020201 ; Serial
                         604800 ; Refresh
                          86400 ; Retry
                        2419200 ; Expire
                         604800); Negative Cache TTL
;

;
; NS Records
;

fresky.tk.      IN      NS      ns1.fresky.tk.
fresky.tk.      IN      NS      ns2.fresky.tk.

;
; A Records (Only Nameservers)
;

ns1     IN      A       176.31.163.33
ns2     IN      A       176.31.163.33

;
; A Records (General)
;
fresky.tk.      IN      A       176.31.163.33
www.fresky.tk.  IN      A       176.31.163.33
ftp.fresky.tk.  IN      A       176.31.163.33
```

**ZONE Reverse *33.163.31.173.in-addr.arpa***

```
;
; BIND reverse data file for local loopback interface
;
$TTL    604800
@       IN      SOA     fresky.tk. admin.fresky.tk. ( 
                     2006020201 ; Serial
                         604800 ; Refresh
                          86400 ; Retry
                        2419200 ; Expire
                         604800); Negative Cache TTL
;

;
; NS Records
;
        IN      NS      ns1.fresky.tk.
        IN      NS      ns2.fresky.tk.
;
; PTR Records (Only NameSever)
;
33.163.31.176.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR     ns1.fresky.tk.
33.163.31.176.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR     ns2.fresky.tk.

;
; PTR Records (General)
;
33.163.31.176.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR     ftp.fresky.tk.
33.163.31.176.in-addr.arpa.     IN      PTR     www.fresky.tk.
```

**/etc/hosts && /etc/resolv.con**

```
# Your system has configured 'manage_etc_hosts' as True.
# As a result, if you wish for changes to this file to persist
# then you will need to either
# a.) make changes to the master file in /etc/cloud/templates/hosts.tmpl
# b.) change or remove the value of 'manage_etc_hosts' in
#     /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg or cloud-config from user-data
176.31.163.33 fresky.tk fresky
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts

search fresky.tk
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Sorry, but since your site is very large I could not find it. Then I was also desperate by the problem. Next time I will be very careful

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to register glue records at https://my.freenom.com

(My Domains / Manage Domain / Management tools / Register glue records)

Add `176.31.163.33` as IP address for `ns1.fresky.tk` and `ns2.fresky.tk`

Comment: Thanks, you are resolving my big problem. This solution function also godaddy host domani.